# How Can i receive SMS and save it in my application and delete it from the native inbox

Tags: java, android, sms

i am developing android application and my application will let people send and receive SMS from unique number

i did that but i faced some problems : 
problem #1 :
1- the Message does not saved. mean my application just appear one message and delete the pervious one. should i create custom inbox to save all the conversation?if yes can you give me tutorial?my because i want my application show the user all the messages between the user and unique number.

problem #2: 
2- i want the SMS appear in my application not in the native inbox! i did that but it also appear in native how can i delete it from native?

Answer (score 0):

Forget making custom inbox, your app should be listen to receiving sms. When one received, read it, and save it in your own app, in preferences or database, and delete the original sms.

You can do the desired operations via working with sms content provider, and listening to sms receive intent.

[THIS](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/15/android-listen-for-incoming-sms-messages/) is an example that may help.